# Call to undefined function get_field_id() in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_field_id() in E:\wamp\www\customfield\wp-content\plugins\custom-widget2\update.php on line 6.

1. i am using ajax to create second dropdown. my ajax page name is update.php but in response give me this error Call to undefined function get_field_id().
2. i making a plugin for widgit

   ```
           echo $ret='<select id="'.get_field_id('test2').';" name="">';

                $categories=  get_categories();
                 $categoryid="";
                 $categoryid=5;
                 $taxonomy_names = get_object_taxonomies($status);
                 $taxonomy_name  =$taxonomy_names[0];
                 $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy_name);
                 foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term):
                 option = '<option value="' .$tax_term->name . '" ';

                 if ($cat->cat_ID == $categoryid) :
                     $option .= ' selected = "selected" ';
                 endif;
                    $option .=  '">';
                    $option .= $tax_term->name;
                    $option .= '</option>';
                    $ret.=$option;
                    echo $option;
                endforeach;
           $ret.="</select>'";
   ```

   update.php

please help me......

Comment: you have to include the `wp-blog-header.php` file, that is in the root folder of the wp installation.

Comment: Sajid Anwar if you have a question, make a comment below the answer, dont make an edit to the question. From your (rejected) edit, did you use the correct path tp wp-blog-header?

Comment: $this->get_field_id('test2') is not working still. i include at the top of the page include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/customfield/wp-blog-header.php' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is out of scope.

To fix add

```
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
```

at the top of your file